# how to record video of current screen activity programmatically in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to record screen video of current running activity from same activity ?
I know how to take screenshot of current activity but don't have any idea about taking screen video record. How would I start with it ? I don't know how to start it.

Comment: You could try using [Android ScreenCast](https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) or something similar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no APIs yet in Android to do this directly. However, you could take screenshots of the app, and then merge them to make a video out of the images.

However, this process is quite tedious, and would probably take a lot of research and investigation.

Since you know how to take screenshots, a good starting point would be to look for libraries/APIs that can take in a series of images, and convert them into a video.

**ffmpeg/JMF** could be two good starting points.